# Which is the correct usage of the verb "overlap": "overlaps" or "overlaps with"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

Which one is correct, "overlaps" or "overlaps with"?

1. Your vacation period **overlaps** John's.
2. Your vacation period **overlaps with** John's.

Comment: Hello, dmz73. What do dictionaries say? Do they give helpful example sentences? You may still have a valid question, but ELU expects reasonable research to be shown.

Comment: I agree with [foxfirebrand's view at wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/overlap-vs-overlap-with.248347/): << The preposition 'with' is used [after 'overlap/s'] with concepts more than with concrete objects.' >>.  I'd use 'Your vacation period overlaps with John's.' but never 'The roof overlaps with the gable'. I'll transfer this, with examples, to an 'answer' if you add dictionary references.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Whilst I agree that people do say "overlaps with", - e.g. with such as holidays - I am not clear how that came to be. The OED does not provide a separate sense category for conceptual overlaps, though some examples are of such. But the number that include *with* are very limited. The preposition, to my mind, would seem quite unnecessary.

Comment: @WS2 I'd hoped OP would do their own research. 'The OED' really isn't a good enough label here; when was your copy last updated? [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overlap) certainly includes the 'overlaps with' variant but only for 'acts and activities'. There are almost 4 million Google hits for "overlaps with". It's idiomatic. Do you never use 'fought against' / 'juggle with' or 'rule over'?

Comment: *Overlapped with* is idiomatic, but is less than a century old. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overlapped+the%2C+overlapped+with+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coverlapped%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coverlapped%20with%20the%3B%2Cc0). It now seems to be more common than transitive *overlapped*. I don't think the dictionaries have caught up with usage yet.

Comment: So only *overlapped* was correct in 1900; possibly only *overlapped with* will be correct in 2100. Right now, use either. The transitive use seems to be more common for physical overlaps, and *with* seems to be more common with temporal and conceptual overlaps, but both are used in both senses.

Comment: @PeterShor OED sense 3b is listed as intransitive, the first example being from 1799:   *R. Kirwan Geol. Ess. 285   In the Pyrenees, they sometimes overlap*. Only one of the seven examples contains the word "with", that being the most recent: 2002   *Proteomics Weekly (Nexis) 7 Oct. 5   The beginning sequence of most peptides overlapped with the ends of others, they noted*. as to Edwin's inquiry as to when "my copy" was updated - as I have mentioned numerous times before I use the latest on-line edition, available in the UK free-of-charge to most people who pay council tax.

Comment: The answer is yes, they are both "correct".  Each is grammatical, understandable, not unusual or odd.

Answer (score 4):

You use "overlaps with" if the overlapping is symmetrical -- ie, one side is not somehow eclipsing the other but rather both sides are equal participants in the coincidence.  Eg, Fred's schedule overlaps with John's.

You use plain "overlaps" if there is a reasonably clear distinction between the "overlapper" and the "overlappee".  Eg, the carpet overlaps the vinyl floor.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to say about partly coincidence in time, you should use *with*: Your vacation period overlaps with John's.
See other examples from [English Oxford living dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overlap):

> - The house of four girls also followed this pattern and two of their three months overlapped with two of the birthday months of my house.
> - The game's 7.30 am kick off, with the final whistle at 9.15 am, meant the game overlapped with the start of the school day.
> - That period overlaps with the breeding period for puffins at both colonies (mid-April through late August).
> - Peter, am I remembering correctly that your time as a participant at the Jan van Eyck Akademie overlapped with Jan van Toorn's final year there?